# ListView that imitates Windows Explorer

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

How can I make a `ListView` imitate the `ListView` in Windows Explorer on the right side. Like how can I get icons in the `ListView` and get the arrows?

Comment: The right side of Explorer uses a ListView, not a TreeView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the icons by using Google Image search.  To create the ListView, you could do something like this is XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ListViewSource}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Width="25">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Image Source="{Binding Icon}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FileName}" Width="250"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Date Modified" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding DateModified}" Width="100"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Type" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FileType}" Width="100"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Size" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FileSize}" Width="100"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

The next step is to create an ObservableCollection to hold all of the items in your list and call it ListViewSource.  You can populate this collection with actual FileDirectory information, or your own kind of list.  You'll then want to create your logic as to what happens when you doubleclick on an item.  Since your question didn't specify to what detail you want the ListView to work, I'm going to stop there.  Let us know if you want it to behave just like Windows Explorer, and we'll try to help you out.